# PHP Regex help required

Tags: php, regex

I have a request for a bit of help, not so complicate as I think but I could not figure out:

This is my regex pattern:

`/:\s*'([^:]*)'/g` (I use it without flag g by preg_match_all())

This is the string to search (usually from jqValidate):

`{ messages : { required :   'This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!', dateISO : 'This is a test...' } , rules : { dateISO : true , required : true } }`

This is what I get and want to get:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => :   'This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!'
        1 => :  'This is a test...'
    )
    1 => array(
        0 => This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!
        1 => This is a test...
    )
)
```

This is the problem:

This pattern - I spent hours to figure out as is (I´m not well practiced) - works good but only as long as I do not need a : (colon).
If I use a colon in a message text between single quotes, that message does not match any more.

Mostly I tried to play around with the negation of the colon but I had no idea how to negate a group like "match all occurrences but colons, "only if" they are not lead by at least one single quote and anything between the single quote and the colon".

To make it a bit more clear what I meant above:

`Example: This is a plausible use of a colon in a jqValidate message.`

`'Example': We probably do not use a colon together with single quotes like this.`

`Any 'text' here: This is a very unusual 'portion of text'!`

I hope you see, what is my problem. Any useful help would be very appreciated.

Thanx in advance,

Regards Ingmar

Comment: You should tell whoever is generating this text to figure out how to emit proper JSON text instead of trying to make it up themselves.

Comment: @chris85 it looks like some bastardized homemade JSON. Identifiers are not quoted, for starters, which makes it not JSON. Also broken quoting.

Comment: There is really no solution until you define some structure. The biggest problem is that there is no delimiter quoting inside the string. Example, this could just as easily be valid  `'This '` asdf `' "asdf" field is required!', dateISO : 'This is a test...'`

Comment: @miken32 one of us is misunderstanding the spirit of stackoverflow. Neither did I ask if this is valid JSON, nor do I believe that it is valid JSON. This is proprietary meta data for an older version of jqValidate and as a matter of fact I do have to work with it at this time. Thank you for your - also if not very helpful - reply.

Comment: You are the one coming here with a Sisyphean task expecting someone to take their time to solve it for you! This is not something easy (possible?) to do, and modifying the source of the data would be far more likely to succeed, if it's possible. Do you have a link to the source code for this program that's generating the data?

Comment: Please do not misunderstand my comment from above. As you can see in my own answer below, I could solve it already. At all I couldn't have sent you any link to that WebApp, it is an inhouse application. Believe me, I am very grateful if somebody takes his/her time to give me some help, so on you! But if there was a possibility to solve it in a different way, I had already done it. Thank you so much for your time and I hope, my solution could be interesting for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you, who are interested in the solution I worked out my self and for myself in future time, here is how I solved it:

Given string is (* Before you comment the not escaped quotes in quotes, read the end of my posting!):

`{ messages : { required :   'This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!', dateISO : 'This is a test...' } , rules : { dateISO : true , required : true } }`

---

**Forget about this!!! I fooled my self, point No. 1 is not needed at all, as (in case of jqValidate) there is no other section existing like "messages", letting the DEV define TEXT-IN-QUOTES!!! Just jump over to point No. 2!!!**

**But of course the basic principle remains.**

**/***

<strike>1. Get only the messages out of the whole trimmed string:</strike>

`^(?:\{\s*messages\s*:\s*\{){1}(.*)(?:\}\s*,(?:.*)\}){1}$`

The resulting array of preg_match will contain the string to work with on index[1](https://regex101.com/r/TxM02y/1):

`required :   'This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!', dateISO : 'This is a test...'`

***/**

---

2. Tickle out the respective messages of the string (here comes the magic):

`:\s*\'((?:(?!\'\s*,(?:.*):\s*\'(?:.*)).)+)\'`

The resulting array of preg_match_all will contain now **ALL** messages in sub-array with index[1](https://regex101.com/r/TxM02y/1) and you can do whatever you want (clean, replace " with ', trim(), addslashes(), rebuild it, replace faulty entries in DB, etc...).

(*) BTW: In this system the admin-users (not the developers) already wrote thousands of jqValidate rules and messages to the DB and yet there was no validation for faulty entries like this in the system. Before I search and clean all of those entries by hand or let the admin-users rewrite their work of years, I choose the way to clean it by a tiny little script with Regular Expressions.
That´s what Regular Expressions are for... At least, the way I understood.

If you are interested in how it looks: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TxM02y/1)

And: **Yes**, you can use single quotes in jqValidate - as long as you escape it (e.g. by addslashes()):

[image: Single quotes in a jqValidate message]

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work:

Regexp:

```
/(?<=required)\s:\s+\'(.+)\',|(?<=dateISO)\s:\s+\'(.+)\'/g
```

Input:

```
{ messages : { required :   'This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!', dateISO : 'This is a test...' } , rules : { dateISO : true , required : true } }
```

Output:

```
This 'asdf' "asdf" field is required!
This is a test...
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=required)\s:\s+\'(.+)\',|(?<=dateISO)\s:\s+\'(.+)\'/';
$str = '{ messages : { required :   \'This \'asdf\' "asdf" field is required!\', dateISO : \'This is a test...\' } , rules : { dateISO : true , required : true } }';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/UD7pgq/2

Comment: Thank you for your constructive input. Two problems: 1. required and dateISO are only two of many flags. This flags change from case to case. 2. The white space in the input string represents only the fact, that human input could from what reason ever be full of useless spaces. My target is to delete ALL white spaces BUT that ones in between single quotes (in the message). If I would simply kill all spaces, message would look like: Thisisatest... or what ever. Thank you for your kind help.